# Build a layer in Keras or Tensorflow to reshape and mul the input

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Here are the steps.

1. The layer gets an input, call it input A, which shape is (None,5,5,100).
2. Reshape A into (None,25,100)
3. Copy A to B
4. Transpose B to shape (None,100,25)
5. Dot B and A (except the batch dimension) and get the result C, which shape is (None,100,100)
6. Reshape C into (None,100,100,1)

It is easy in torch, but I have to implement it in keras so I have no idea. It has confused me for more than 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Given an input:

```
from keras.layers import *


inp = Input((5,5,100)) #or the output of a layer coming before this

out = Reshape((25,100))(inp)   
out = Lambda(operation, output_shape = (100,100))(out)
out = Reshape((100,100,1))(out)
```

Where operation is:

```
import keras.backend as K

def operation(x):
    xT = K.permute_dimensions(x,(0,2,1)) #batch axes 0 is kept, 1 and 2 are swaped    
    return K.batch_dot(x,xT,axes=[1,2])
```

---

If you're using a sequential model:

```
model.add(Reshape(25,100))
model.add(Lambda(operation, output_shape = (100,100)))
model.add(Reshape((100,100,1)))
```

---

If you want everything inside a single layer:

```
def operation(x):
    x2 = K.reshape(x,(25,100))
    x2T = K.permute_dimensions(x,(0,2,1))
    d = K.batch_dot(x2,x2T,axes=[1,2])
    return K.reshape(d,(100,100,1))

myLayer = Lambda(operation, output_shape=(100,100,1))
```

If you want multiple instances of that layer:

```
def myLayer():
    return Lambda(operation, output_shape=(100,100,1))
```